# How to find out the visits made in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana-4, elasticsearch-net

We are using ElasticSearch v1.5.1, we have also configured the marvel logs.
We use it for Kibana 4.0.1, as well as for our search based results using NEST code.
Our Kibana comprises of multiple indexes and various dashboards associated to each of them.
Our application uses Elastic Search to search the results of our application faster.

Is there a way to capture the following from the marvel logs or any other possible way.

1. No. of hits made to a particular index
2. No. of visits made to the whole elastic store
3. Identifying the user who has visited the elastic store.
4. The visualization which the user has chosen in Kibana.

Thanks and Regards,
Hema